# Aliasing multiple classes in C#

Tags: c#, templates, alias

I want to (am trying to) make my code more readable. I have been using the following class aliasing.

```
using Histogram = EmpiricScore<int>;
using FeatureHistogram = Dictionary<string, EmpiricScore<int>>;
```

But I think something like (note:  I'm attempting to describe `FeatureHistogram` in terms of `Histogram` here, rather than `EmpiricScore<int>>`):

```
using Histogram = EmpiricScore<int>;
using FeatureHistogram = Dictionary<string, Histogram>;
```

Seems more readable (the dependencies can go much deeper, what if I create a Hierarchical feature histogram), and easier to re-factor (if I happen to decide that the name Histogram is unfortunate). But the compiler won't do it. Why ? Any way to circumvent this ?

Creating new classes seems a little bit overkill...

Comment: @Micky Duncan. Thank you, but I can't find my answer in this post. My question is specifically about "stacked" aliasing

Comment: if you do `using Histogram = EmpiricScore<int>;` outside namespace then `using FeatureHistogram = Dictionary<string, Histogram>;` Inside namespace is possible. but thats not a answer for much deeper dependencies.

Comment: Ah I didn't notice that, please disregard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But the compiler won't do it. Why ?

compiler won't do it according to C# specification 9.4.1:

A `using-alias-directive` introduces an identifier that serves as an alias for a namespace or type within the immediately enclosing compilation unit or namespace body.

```
using-alias-directive:
using   identifier   =   namespace-or-type-name   ;
```

> The order in which `using-alias-directives` are written has no significance, and resolution of the `namespace-or-type-name` referenced by a `using-alias-directive` is not affected by the `using-alias-directive` itself or by other `using-directives` in the immediately containing compilation unit or namespace body.
>
> In other words, the `namespace-or-type-name` of a `using-alias-directive` is resolved as if the immediately containing compilation unit or namespace body had no using-directives.

```
namespace N1.N2 {}
namespace N3
{
    using R2 = N1;          // OK
    using R3 = N1.N2;       // OK
    using R4 = R2.N2;       // Error, R2 unknown
}
```

options:
1. as `M.kazem Akhgary` suggested in a comment, define new namespace

[demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6YT4kG)

```
using Histogram = System.Collections.Generic.List<int>;

namespace TEST
{
    using FeatureHistogram = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, Histogram>;

    public class Program
    {    
        public static void Main()
        {
            var x = new Histogram();
            Console.WriteLine(x.GetType());

            var y = new FeatureHistogram();
            Console.WriteLine(y.GetType());
        }   
    }
}
```

2. create classes for deeper dependencies

Answer (score 4):

> Creating new classes seems a little bit overkill...

I don't find it an overkill because if you design a class which wraps the `Dictionary<string, Histogram>` (your class should implement `IDictionary<string, Histogram>` and have a private `Dictionary<string, Histogram>` property backing the data) you're enforcing *reusability*, which is one of the best selling points of object-oriented programming.

For example, your implementation would look as follows:

```
public class FeatureHistorgram : IDictionary<string, Historam>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Histogram> _data = new Dictionary<string, Histogram>();

    public void Add(string key, Histogram value)
    {
        _data.Add(key, value);
    }

    // ... and the rest of IDictionary<TKey, TValue> interface members...
}
```

Comment: Question: is it better to implement `IDictionary` or to inherit from `Dictionary`? Without reading your answer, I would have used the latter (and avoid the usage of `_data` and use `base` instead).

Comment: @XavierPeña Well, it depends on the case. If you want to customize how items are added to the underlying dictionary the interface approach is the right one. If you don't plan to do something before/after adding an item to the dictionary, deriving `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` should be enough...

Comment: "If you want to customize how items are added to the underlying dictionary the interface approach is the right one": then what are the disadvantages of overriding `Add` in the `Dictionary` inheritance? (While trying to formulate the question, I realize how hard it is to not sound like a smartass in SO... not my intention at all, just trying to learn)

Comment: @XavierPeña You should read the docs. `Add` isn't a virtual method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/k7z0zy8k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It is less a question of overkill or not, the important part seems that when declaring a new class, it will not be bilaterally assignment-compatible any more with the original, lengthy class name, as opposed to a mere alias.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Yeah, btw, my point is aliasing is a bad idea. I prefer to see actual type names than confusing my mind with N alias which mean the same class...